# How to keep track of changes after release new version for Node app?

Tags: node.js

I just made some changes and changed the version number for my Node app. However, I don't know where exactly can I put in some note so that next time, when I go back to my project, I know let say version 2.0 has "X" feature added on.

I wish to have something like this

```
Version 2.0
- Added x feature
- Changed x function
```

In my app, I see there is a package.json file with

```
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Food API",
```

and after I made changes, I updated it to

```
"version": "2.0",
"description": "Food API",
```

but there is no option for me to add some note

Can you please share how do you handle this situation? I don't use Github by the way. Thanks!

Comment: This is what changelog.md is for. If you're doing this for yourself... well, that's what Git log is for.

Comment: I dont see changelog in my node app. Do I have to create one?

Comment: Yes. If you didn't create it, there's none. Check open source Github projects for examples. You can keep it DRYer by having proper commit messages and generating changelog from Git history, e.g https://github.com/lob/generate-changelog